# Syslog ng connectivity issue

Tags: java, syslog-ng

I am new to syslog ng and wanted to know if there is any way to check the combination of  ip, port and protocol configuration for a syslog ng connection?
I know that one can check the ip and port, but wasnt sure how to handle scenarios where the ip and port are correct, but the protocol is incorrect(how it can be verified in Java)

I have been looking at the configuration of syslog ng(but no luck yet)